# 'auth' middleware in lumen throwing error

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, lumen, laravel-middleware

I am testing out lumen for the first time. Trying out `auth` middleware throws an error. I want to know whether such a middleware is shipped with lumen or do we need to implement our own?
This is my routes file

```
$app->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ($app) {

    $app->get('/', ['as' => 'api', 'uses' => 'ApiController@index']);
});
```

and this is the error when trying to access the route

```
ErrorException in Manager.php line 137:
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\Guard' does not have a method 'handle'
```

Comment: The code you posted is not relevant to the question

Comment: That's true i guess. But i thought `auth` middleware was included but it's throwing error.

Comment: I don't think Lumen has the auth middleware. Unless you added this manually?

Answer (score 5):

As you see, `auth` in Lumen container bound to `Illuminate\Support\Manager\AuthManager`. So, yeah, you have to create your own middleware. This is an example for your case.

Make your own middleware in `app/Http/Middleware`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                // Lumen has no Redirector::guest(), this line is put the intended URL to a session like Redirector::guest() does
                app('session')->put('url.intended', app('url')->full());
                // Set your login URL here
                return redirect()->to('auth/login', 302);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

After this, bind your middleware in container. You can do this in `bootstrap/app.php`. Add these two lines before `return`.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Load The Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next we will include the routes file so that they can all be added to
| the application. This will provide all of the URLs the application
| can respond to, as well as the controllers that may handle them.
|
*/

$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    require __DIR__.'/../app/Http/routes.php';
});

$app->bind('App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate', 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate');
$app->alias('App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate', 'middleware.auth');
```

Now, instead of using `auth` in your middleware, use `middleware.auth`:

```
$app->group(['middleware' => 'middleware.auth'], function ($app) {
    $app->get('/', ['as' => 'api', 'uses' => 'ApiController@index']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually all you need to do is to uncomment these lines in `bootstrap/app.php`

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);
```